# Chrome Mobile, Change System Navigation Bar (Back, Home, Recent Buttons) Background Color?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

recent update to google chrome on android makes the navigation bar background white & dark themed sites look crappy with this at the bottom imo (screenshot below).

im wondering if there is a way to control the color with meta tags or something similar to how the top area theme color can be controlled like...

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#353535" />
```

or any sorta way to alter this? even just setting to black would be great, dont really need a custom color. tried looking around through documentation but couldnt find anything exact, might not be doable. apologize if my terminology might be off.

screenshot of the white navigation bar at the bottom for reference
[image]

Comment: Here is the chrome issue tracking this problem: Star it to vote to get more attention to it. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=797527

Answer (score 6):

This is not fixable in Chrome 67. Whether or not it will be fixed is tracked in this chromium issue. Star it if you're interested in the issue getting more attention

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=797527

Answer (score 4):

According to what I saw, there isn't a way to do this now. Maybe Google will add a way to do this in a future update but for now they are apparently using this to limit the burn in on the screens.

So we are unfortunately stuck with it for now

Comment: That seems to make no sense since apps are used more than the browser and apps don't have this limitation. As an example Google's own Calendar app has a white on black nav bar, So does Hangouts, Keep, Camera, Clock, Docs, Drive, etc...  Of course that doesn't mean there is a way to do it, only that it can't possibly be for the burn in reason

Comment: I saw that a few people said the same thing. But I saw that someone said that it will be less visible or something

Comment: I found the chrome issue and linked it above in the comments. Hopefully they'll do something about it