# How to change Android bottom navigation bar on website?-

Tags: progressive-web-apps, android-bottomnav

I can change **TOP** navigation bar for Android devices with this code on my website:

```
function address_mobile_address_bar() {
    $color = "black";

    // Chrome, Firefox OS, Opera and Vivaldi
    echo '<meta name="theme-color" content="' . $color . '">';

    // Windows Phone
    echo '<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="' . $color . '">';

    // iOS Safari
    echo '<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">';
    echo '<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'address_mobile_address_bar' );
```

But how can I change color of the **BOTTOM** navigation bar of a smartphone **on a website / PWA**?

[image]
   
[image]

Comment: Same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710595/chrome-mobile-change-system-navigation-bar-back-home-recent-buttons-backgro

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome Mobile, Change System Navigation Bar (Back, Home, Recent Buttons) Background Color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710595/chrome-mobile-change-system-navigation-bar-back-home-recent-buttons-backgro)